# How in JavaScript do you compare two similar values that are being used and assign them accordingly?

Tags: javascript

So I have a form in my Rails app that needs to pass the option value using abbreviation. So for example:

```
<label for="country-north-america">Country</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="country-north-america" id="country-north-america>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>

<label for="state">State></label>
 <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state">
  <option value="CA">California</option>
```

Then in my JS file I am pulling in the states to assign it to account executives:

```
let users = [
 {
  default: true,
  name: 'Bill',
  states: ['South America', 'Canada', 'Asia']
 },
  name: 'Frank',
  states: ['AK', 'AZ', 'CA']
 }]
```

Then I have further:

```
var findUserByStateOrRegion = function(stateOrRegion) {
  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var u = users[i];
    if (u.states.includes(stateOrRegion)) {
      return u;
    }
  }
};
```

So the problem is that the assignment is going to Frank for Canada because the value is CA. However if I update Canada in JS to be CA then California will go to Bill. What I'm trying to figure out is how to assign Canada to Bill using CA as the value.

Edit: Tried the following:

```
  var findUserByStateOrRegion = function(stateOrRegion) {
  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var u = users[i];
    if (u.states === 'CA' && u.country === 'CA') {
      return u.default;
    }
    else (u.states.includes(stateOrRegion)) {
      return u;
    }
  }
};
```

Then put on the default ae the following:

```
{
 default: true,
 name: 'Bill',
 country: 'CA',
 states: ['South America', 'CA', 'Asia']
}
```

Did not work. No errors or anything present. But that did not apparently hit the country.

Comment: Have separate functions for looking at countries and looking at states? Why does the same function have to handle both? Also use separate properties for countries and states.

Comment: Separate properties for `state`, `country` and `continent` ... don't mix the data this way or you are shooting yourself in the foot

Comment: Asia and South America aren't states.

Comment: Based on ISO standards for two letter abbreviations California and Canada both use CA. Which is why this is an issue. States is being used because out of the seven account execs six of them are handling states and the last, the default, is handling everything else. I imagine the developer that wrote this originally thought it impractical to create an additional function to look for country.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I believe there may be a mistake in your JS.

```
let users = [
 {
  default: true,
  name: 'Bill',
  states: ['South America', 'Canada', 'Asia']
 },{
  name: 'Frank',
  states: ['AK', 'AZ', 'CA']
 }]
```

Based off your scenario, it looks like Frank and Bill should be seperate objects, instead of having bill be a child within Frank.

In this case, what you're attempting to do is assign a particular value to 2+ outcomes. The standard solution in this case would be to use a 2 digit code for States/Provinces, while Countries use a 3 digit code.

Think of your states "key" as a primary key/variable. You're changing the value of that variable, and will instead need another key.

ALTERNATIVELY, if the 2 digit country code is a requirement, you need to uniquely identify the country. You could add another property to your object to store countries and states/provinces separately (I wouldnt recommend this, but this is an alternative).

Best of luck.

----EDIT----

Upon further review. Can you clarify if you're matching CA: California and CA: Canada or if you're function (.include) is matching to both "**CA**lifornia" and "**CA**nada", if that's the case, it's due to non-strict matching. 
If you enforce "strict" matching for your comparison, you'll only return an EXACT match to your requirements.

Comment: Two digit country/state code is a requirement to pass along the value to HubSpot form. If Canada is switched to the value of "CA" in my JS array then it's hitting Bill and then Bill gets California as well.

Comment: in that case, i would recommend this scenario:

"If the 2 digit country code is a requirement, you need to uniquely identify the country. You could add another property to your object to store countries and states/provinces separately."

Comment: What are the exact requirements, and what are the restrictions on changes. If I know more, i may be able to provide better detail.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of messing with state/country/region and matching specifically on those that hit those exact objects went with matching on the number of objects being matched since it was an issue with one person in particular getting only two.

```
 var findUserByLocations = function(locations) {
  var match;
  if (locations.length !== 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      match = users.find(function(user) { 
        return user.states.includes(locations[i]); 
      });
      if (match) return match;
    }
  }
  return findDefaultUser();
};
```

And yes I'm aware that if there comes a time when this applies to someone else it falls apart.